# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a primitive of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$. Now, under what condition does a primitive of f exists and if it exists how do we find it and its domain?

I think, if $f$ is continuous, then its primitive exists. But if $f$ is not continuous on its domain, how do we know about primitive?

Comment: How do you define primitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by the primitive of $f$, you mean the antiderivative of $f$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_function.

To answer your question:

Yes, if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then the indefinite integral $F$ defined by $F(z) = \int_a^z f(x)dx$ is a primitive (or antiderivative) of $f$.

If $f$ is not continuous, $f$ may still have a primitive, but there's no general rule as to how to find it. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_function#Antiderivatives_of_non-continuous_functions) on wikipedia for more info on primitives of non-continuous functions.

Hope this helped!